# How to get the wsdl file from endpoint URL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Can anybody now hoe to get the wsdl file from the  endpoint URL.

When I try to hit the endpoint from the browser, I am getting the below error.

URL:  http://****.com/MyBenefits/webservices

Error:

```
   SOAP RPC Router
    Sorry, I don't speak via HTTP GET- you have to use HTTP POST to talk to me.
```

When I try the same with SOAP UI I got the below error message.

Intial WSDL/WADL: http://******.com/MyBenefits/webservices?WSDL

Error:

[image]

Can I know any way to get the wsdl file from the endpoint URL.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but my url is: http://*****/soap/ps/servlet/rpcroute

Try SoapUI!

1. Create a new project, just write a project name and check the Add REST Service box
2. Write your Service Endpoint: http://****.com/MyBenefits/webservices and check Extract Resouce/Method box
3. Click on Extract Params, don't worry if you can't see any params..
4. Rename Method Name, and choose your HTTP Method as POST ("Sorry, I don't speak via HTTP GET- you have to use HTTP POST to talk to me.")
5. Now, the Request 1 window is open, change Media Type to text/xml, paste your XMl Request and click en Play (green button)
   My XMl request is:

   ```
   <soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns="urn:YourEndPoint" >
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
       <YourOperationName>
           <YourParams>
           </YourParams>
         </YourOperationName>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```

Good luck!

Comment: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity, im getting this response from post man for similar kind of request, any idea ?